# How to get information about time when an item cached in azure caching?

Tags: caching, azure

Since I am caching an item in azure cache appfabric and in some cases i need information when a item was cached (like datetime of caching), So azure cache provide any such kind of function  to provide this data about timing. By using this i will find out whether item is cached on current day or some other day.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the WAAF Caching has this information. You might need to add the time in your data by yourself.